# validation check is not working in phonegap. when i click button nothing works.

Tags: validation, cordova

problem is with validation if the fields are empty then it should give alert but no response on click. is this validation jquery error or function is not being called properly?

i checked in all over and i tried different java script, it didnt worked, any solutions

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="css/theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
   <!--wait till cordnova loads-->
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
            navigator.splashscreen.show();
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }
    </script>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="b" >
    <div id="header" data-role="header">
    <h3>Login Page</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <form action="" name="myLogin">
    <div data-role="content">
    <div class="username" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="username"> Username </label>
    <input name="username" id="usename" placeholder="Enter Username" value="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="password" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" value="" type="text">
    </div>

    <input id="login" value="login" type="button" onclick="validationcheck();">
    <input id="register" value="register" type="button" onclick="register();">
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
     function validationcheck(){

      if (document.mylogin.username.value == "") {

       alert("Please Enter Username.");

       document.mylogin.username.focus(); 

      } else if (document.mylogin.password.value == "") {

       alert("Please Enter Password.");

       document.mylogin.password.focus();
      }
      else
       {

         alert("success");
       }
     }
     </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this one nothing to do with phonegap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstl of all, fix typo in user name input id: from "usename" to "username". And now how your function should look like:

```
 function validationcheck(){
  if ($("#username").val() == "") {

   alert("Please Enter Username.");

   $("#username").focus(); 

  } else if ($("#password").val() == "") {

   alert("Please Enter Password.");

   $("#password").focus();
  }
  else
   {

     alert("success");
   }
 }
```

You can also do it without using JQuery: just use

```
document.getElementById('username').value
document.getElementById('username').focus()
```

Comment: thanks bro! it works.. sorry i don't have reputation to vote your answer.. thnx

Comment: @Omar well, Dato' Mohammad Nurdin tried to play dishonest game by voting down other answers and voting up his own answers.

Comment: He got banned for playing such games.

Answer (score 0):

try this one bro

remove your `form` tag and `onclick="validationcheck();"`

html

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="username" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="username"> Username </label>
    <input name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" value="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="password" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" value="" type="text">
    </div>

    <input id="login" value="login" type="button" >
    <input id="register" value="register" type="button" onclick="register();">
    </div>
```

use jquery instead traditional javascript

javascript

```
$("#login").click(function() {
    if ($("#username").val() == "") {
        alert("Please enter username.");
    } else if ($("#password").val() == "") {
        alert("Please enter password.");
    } else {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

Comment: you know, it doesn't look good to vote down other people answers for nothing and vote up your own answer...